# angular 2 global variables like isLoggedIn or userRoles

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-scope, global-variables

what is the best way to maintain global variable in `angular2`. I am unable to find a way to maintain a global variable through out the application. After user logged into the application I need `User` object which has user details and `isLoggedIn` values in all other components. Here is what I am doing ...

```
@Injectable()
export class AppGlobals {
    public isUserLoggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    public currentUser: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
    setLoginStatus(isLoggedIn) {
        this.isUserLoggedIn.next(isLoggedIn);
    }
    setCurrentUser(currentUser) {
        this.currentUser.next(currentUser);
    }
}
```

In loginComponent I am setting up the `user` and `isLoggedIn` details upon successful login

```
login() {
    this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
        .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.appGlobals.setLoginStatus(true);
            this.appGlobals.setCurrentUser(data);
            this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        },
        error => {
            this.alertService.error(error);
            this.loading = false;
        });
}
```

and accessing the value in other component ....

```
export class ProductsComponent {
    currentUser: User;
    isLoggedIn: boolean;
    constructor(private productService: ProductService, private router:Router,
        private confirmationService: ConfirmationService,
        private auth: AuthenticationService,
        private appGlobal: AppGlobals) {
        appGlobal.isUserLoggedIn.subscribe(value => {this.isLoggedIn = value; console.log(value);});  // should be true
        appGlobal.currentUser.subscribe(value => {console.log(value); this.userRole = value}); // should have user data
        .....
    }
    .....
}
```

In `ProductsComponent` values for `isLoggedIn` and `currentUser` are correct for the first time but when I refresh the browser I am getting `false for isLoggedIn` and `null for user`. Not sure what I am doing wrong and where. Is it totally wrong way to maintain the user and loggedIn status for all components? I don't want to go with `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: When you refresh, the temporary memory (assignment) gets erased! So you shouldn't be refreshing your browser! Or you may choose to cache it `document.cache`

Comment: @Smit thanks for the information, I didn't know that it will erase the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use localStorage

when you login you set the localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ email: email, id: id }));
```

any component that needs user to be logged in check the localStorage

```
localStorage.getItem('currentUser')
```

and on logout

```
localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
```

Comment: I got to know from others that having userDetails in `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` is not a best way , so wanted to go with `global variables`... I am just going with the suggestions as it's been three weeks I started learning Angular2

Comment: just want one more clarification on clearing `localStorage` is there anyway we can clear `localStorage` whenever we restart the application?

Comment: that is what the last call i mentioned removeItem does

Comment: You can also use a subject and subscribe to the subject in each component to know if the subject which holds the user is still there or not. Hope you are familiar with subjects in angular 2

Comment: I am using `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject` if you see above but in other component it is giving correct value when I refresh the browser it gets null values

yes I am clearing localstorage value with `localStorage.clear()` but my question is user didn't logged out but closed the browser or when application get restarted again these`localStorage` should be cleaned.

Comment: In the ProductsComponent i don't see a userRole in this.userRole defined in the constructor. Did you mean to use currentUser     console.log(value); this.currentUser = value  ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137039/discussion-between-user1653027-and-vinay-prabhakaran).

Comment: Using localStorage for user roles is not a good idea since localStorage can be edited within the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a service that you provide in `AppModule`. It will be a singleton and available throughout your application and have the same lifetime as the Angular application.

Every component, directive, pipe, and service can inject it to access its status or subscribe to its observables.

Comment: Services are basic building blocks in Angular. Just check the docs. There are dozens of examples with code running in StackBlitz